# PHP Write into SimpleXML and Save

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Having the following code, I need to do something:

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ToDoList>
    <Item>
        <Name>Complete this xml</Name>
        <Category>Programming</Category>
    </Item>
    <Data>
    </Data>
</ToDoList>
```

PHP

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        b {
            font-size:30px;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size:40px;
        }
        i {
            font-size:18px;
        }
        span {
            font-size:24px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $ToDoList = simplexml_load_file("list/todo.xml");
            $Name = $ToDoList->getName();
            echo("<h1>".$Name."</h1>");
            foreach($ToDoList->children() as $item){
                echo("<b>" . $item->getName() . " : " . $item . "<br></b>");
                foreach($item->attributes() as $name => $value){
                    echo("<i>attr. : " . $name . " = " . $value . "<br></i>");
                }
                foreach($item->children() as $subitem){
                    echo("<span>" . $subitem->getName() . " : " . $subitem . "<br></span>");
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I need to do is:

> To write into xml and then save.

I want to write `<Test>1</Test>` in `<Data></Data>`. After that I want to save it back to `list/todo.php`.

I've tried reading the questions to write and save the xml, but neither of the methods worked.

What code should I use (in php) to solve this problem?

EDIT---

I tried to use this code, but it didn't work:

```
$NewItem = $ToDoList->ToDoList->addChild('Item');
$NewItem->addChild("Name","Test");
$NewItem->addChild("Category","Test");
$ToDoList->asXML("test.xml");
```

Comment: Have you read this?: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: Then I should remove this question, shouldn't I? But I still wish a solution will pop out.

Comment: Also, __How to save to xml?__

Comment: How to save to xml - `asXML` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php)

Comment: What's the problem in my edited code? It said that "Cannot addchild"!

Comment: How to add `<Test>1</Test>` in `<Data></Data>`: `$ToDoList->Data->addChild('Test', '1');`

Comment: Warning: SimpleXMLElement::addChild() [simplexmlelement.addchild]: Cannot add child. Parent is not a permanent member of the XML tree in /home/a7593238/public_html/test/test.php on line 32

Comment: What can I do? There is such warning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this. replace element with your element and child.this is sample code.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml_item = $xml->createElement("Item");
$xml_name = $xml->createElement("Name");
$xml_category = $xml->createElement("Category");
$xml_album->appendChild( $xml_name );
$xml_album->appendChild( $xml_category );
$xml->appendChild( $xml_album );

$xml->save("test.xml");
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry for being rude.

Comment: Can you also transfer my whole code to a method using PHP DOM?

Comment: Hmm, seems delicious.

Comment: What is `$xml_album`?

Comment: Oh I see. _Just a variable_.